# Address json-data sent from PHP to Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I try to pass json-encoded data from my PHP- and MySQL-script back to the page with the ajax-script. The data would have multiple lines, meaning row1, row2 and so on. I pass the data back to the page and want to address the first row/line before I go on to the second and so on. But I can't even address a single one. Not only are urls looking "strange" (instead of slash / I see backslash and slash /), but I can't even get a single result if I address data[1] or else. I used to try several solutions from several posts here without any success.

Here's the PHP-part which is working fine:

```
$data = array();


 $query = "SELECT * FROM `episode_elements` WHERE eid = 1 ORDER BY rank";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
 $data = array();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    //echo $row['audio'];
    //printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row[0],$row[1],$row[2],$row[3],$row[4]);
    $data[0] = $row['audio'];
    $data[1] = $row['image'];
    $data[2] = $row['text'];
    $data[3] = $row['rank'];
    print json_encode($data);
 }
```

Just getting the result from this script is showing a great result:

```
["http:\/\/www.nasa.gov\/mp3\/581097main_STS-1_Dust-it-Off.mp3","https:\/\/cdn.pixabay.com\/photo\/2011\/12\/14\/12\/11\/astronaut-11080_960_720.jpg","NASA","1"]
["http:\/\/www.mostfreebies.com\/PatrioticNostalgicMusic\/music\/USAFB_TheStarSpangledBanner.mp3","https:\/\/cdn.pixabay.com\/photo\/2013\/01\/16\/05\/08\/flag-75047_960_720.jpg","Star Spangled Banner","2"]
```

But there you can already see the backslashes. But then when I pass the data back to my script I can't access it. I can't see data[0] or data[1][1].

How do I fix it? Frankly spoken, JS and Ajax drive me crazy.

```
 function load_data(limit, start)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"episode_content_load.php",
   method:"POST",
   dataType: 'json',
   data:{limit:limit, start:start},
   cache:false,
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#load_data').append(data);
    alert(data[1]);
   }
  });
 }
```

While **$('#load_data').append(data);** works if I don't add the line datatype: JSON, **alert(data[1]);** doesn't show me anything. And this is confusing as it seems to work for others in similar posts.

If you have an idea, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The backslashes don't matter. PHP escapes slashes by default, but you can disable that with the JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES flag if you really want to. However, your response isn't valid JSON. It's several JSON documents, concatenated. Call json_encode only once.

Comment: Peter, may you explain what you mean with call json_encode only once? In php I do so. But maybe I understand you wrong.

Comment: you call it once per row. Instead, use the loop to build some data structure (an array, for instance, but that's really up to you) and then call json_encode once after the loop.

Comment: Peter, that's it. Got the results I wanted. '$data = $row' and the print positioned outside the loop. Now I can address with data[x][y] as I wanted. 
If you create an answer on this I'd like to mark this as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

did you try data[0][1]? This is based on nothing. Pure on guess.

Comment: I did. With json as datatype no response, without it's undefined.